# How to set leadsource in Dynamics crm using api?

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamics-crm

I have a WordPress website and I am using a Gravity Forms CRM addon to create lead in CRM. I need to set lead source which is a dropdown in crm lead. while sending data to crm (via api) I am getting an error:

System.ArgumentException: Incorrect attribute value type System.String Parameter name: leadsourcecode

I tried sending text and number as well but not working.

Answer (score 0):

The **leadsourcecode** field receives a `Edm.Int32` accourding to [WebAPI documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/lead?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9). The following is an example of a create request setting the Lead Source to Advertisement(1):

```
POST /api/data/v9.0/leads
odata-maxversion: 4.0
odata-version: 4.0
accept: application/json
content-type: application/json

{
 "subject": "test api 2",
 "leadsourcecode": 1
 }
```

You can also review the default options for the field in the same [lead entity documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/lead?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9) I mentioned before:

> **Value   Label**
>
> 1     Advertisement
>
> 2     Employee Referral
>
> 3     External Referral
>
> 4     Partner
>
> 5     Public Relations
>
> 6     Seminar
>
> 7     Trade Show
>
> 8     Web
>
> 9     Word of Mouth
>
> 10    Other

Comment: Getting this error:System.ArgumentException: Incorrect attribute value type System.String
 Parameter name: leadsourcecode2018-09-25T05:03:41.0391441Zfalse
 [Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel: Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.TargetAttributeValidationPlugin]
 [c754fdb4-ef2f-4f2c-b49f-186214ab4dcd: TargetAttributeValidationPlugin]

Comment: Could you please update your question and include the full request you're sending? I've tested the one included in my answer this and it's working fine.